am I leading a project in the right way?
My current team is going to adopt the Agile methodology, but no-one has experience with it except me, and there is also some lack of technical skills.
As a result, in each meeting I tend to talk a lot, either about how we do things in Agile, or how we should develop/fix something technically. Most of my suggestions are taken into account/implemented.
However, I am introverted and interacting with others leaves me drained, especially when I have to discuss 3 hours in a day because the stories were not well specified, explain why we do refinements and then review the code of others. This has started to make me feel upset, as there is a huge lack of participation by the rest of the developers.
I have been in other teams where I had some leadership role (informal) on some topics, but there was always an active participation from the others, so that I could understand if my contributions were going in the right direction. Here, my contributions are the only contributions.
I am torn between continuing in this way (because that's what leaders do, isn't it?), or make a step back and leave it as it is, limiting my contributions to development and a normal meeting participation waiting for the next paycheck.
My question is: how do I know if I am leading and if I am doing it in the right way? In case it is, how can I lower the cost of it?

What does your boss think about your performance so far?

@AidaPaul He is very happy

Who made the decision to "adopt the Agile methodology"? It sounds like your team isn't bought into this decision, which is interesting given that you are now favouring individuals and interactions over processes and tools.

@PhilipKendall It came from the top. Input was asked from anyone, but most likely was pointless, we are really a top-down kind of organization. A manager decides, and the game is over. There has been some training in the methodology for the rest of the team, but training and actually doing Agile are miles apart.

Spoiler: you're not agile.

It takes longer to implement Agile than you might think, if your boss is happy, you're probably good!

@PhilipKendall I know, and I think it was clear from the text of the question as well

@PampaNello You might want to add more one on one talks with your team members to find their strengths and encourage them to speak up in the meetings. That way, you can talk about items that they are the only ones working on outside of the meetings.

@DavidR: For me that would be raising the cost.

@DanielR.Collins Yes, it does raise the costs, but it is about actually leading the team. Proper leadership requires knowing the individuals, their strengths and weaknesses, and helping them move forward in a way that pulls the whole team together.

In one shop I worked, a business type walked up to my scrum master, and asked "Are you done with your scrum project as of yet"?   Despite being a stake holder, he had no knowledge or desire to learn agile.
Agile is a skill and different than other methodologies and will differ across organizations based on buy in from management, the team, stake holders, and the customer.  Currently I work in an agile shop with a very mature model, but we do not do planning poker.  This is simply because each team has only one or two SMEs that really know the software, the rest are just newbies that are trying their best with no ability to estimate.
To me, the key to this kind of training is "power down" or "train the trainer".  For example:  I would try to work with my manager to have conducting a lunch and learn be a part of the evaluation process.  Then assign each team member to give a talk on during lunch and learn.  Another option is to rotate who will conduct the scrum each day.
Currently you are providing the training, but the goal should be to have them conduct the training with you providing coordination.
It's important to able to distinguish who actually wants to learn, and who simply does not care.  Like the stake holder in the first paragraph talking to him, does no good, so don't.  He has no desire or ability to understand the back log or whatever, so rather than talking to him, you have to kind of do the job for him.  Discover what he wants and write tickets to throw on the back log.
Part of this is understanding where your manager stands.  The suggestion of doing lunch and learns might fail, if he does not care about such things.
Trying to improve things is your responsibility as a professional.  Recognizing when your suggestions and inputs are being ignored is part of good mental health.
I'd keep trying using the "train the trainer" principles but stop if it fails to provoke any changes.
